# How can I read the second to last line of a text file?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a vb.net application tie part serial numbers into part processing data with a 1 part buffer between the last time the serial number was known and when the processing happens. Basically a part is pulled off of a conveyor on a separate machine and a text file is populated with information from that part. I'm reading the text file and storing the serial number in a local text file. The part is then placed on a two station dial where nothing happens in the front position, but when the part rotates to the rear position, it is processed and data is stored in a different text file.

Because a second part will have been removed from the conveyor and placed on the dial before processing occurs, I want to be able to read the second to last line in the text file that contains the serial numbers in order to tie the correct serial number into the part processing data.

Below is the code I'm using to read the data from the text file that gets populated when a part is removed from the conveyor, pull out the serial number and save it to a separate text file. I can read back the last line of that file just fine, but I can't figure out any way to read back the second to last line.

```
    Dim PrevSerialNum As String
    Dim directory As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("Z:\ReadyForFFT")
    Dim myFile As FileInfo
    Dim Name As String
    PrevSerialNum = ("")

    Do
        myFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()
        Name = Convert.ToString(myFile.Name)
        Name = Name.Remove(10, 4)
        If PrevSerialNum <> Name Then
            'MessageBox.Show(Name)
            Dim txt As System.IO.StreamWriter
            txt = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Serial Numbers\Serial Numbers.txt", True)
            txt.WriteLine(Name)
            txt.Close()
            PrevSerialNum = Name
        Else
            'Do Nothing
        End If
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) It looks like the code for reading the file got missed out - all I can see is code which gets a filename and writes part of it to a file. 2) How large in (KB or MB) will the file that you read be?

Comment: Sorry, when I was writing this I forgot that I ended up just taking the serial number from the name of the text file since the conveyor system creates a new text file for each part number and the name of the file is the serial number. This way I don't have to open the text file at all. The file that I want to read the second to last line of will start over at midnight every day so it should be about 200 KB max.

Comment: If you are implying that the data you want to skip one of is the directory entries, then `myFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).Skip(1).First()`. (Also "directory" is a poor name for a variable when using System.IO because it clashes with Directory in that and could cause strange problems.)

Comment: Thanks! I think that will work better than what I was trying to do. I was trying to save all of the serial numbers into a text file from the names in the directory. But I can skip that step altogether by just taking the second most recent file name in the directory like you showed.

Comment: Seems like a pretty shaky way of getting manufacturing data that needs to be tracked by SN. Can't you just communicate with the machines directly somehow so you can skip all this file IO?

Comment: @topshot absolutely my thought too. Without too much work you could get it working with a SQL server - SQL Express is free pre-production. If you are really running production you would have this stuff in some sort of database anyway. I have seen IPC done with files before and it's been a little comical.

Comment: @djv It's free for production use too. It just has lower limitations than the other versions, e.g. a maximum database size of 10GB.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good to know.

Comment: @djv Here's the quick comparison table: [Compare SQL Server 2017 editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions). It doesn't mention that for full text search you have to hunt down the "Express with Advanced Services" version.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions everyone. I agree, it is a very shaky way of tracking serial numbers. The rest of the assembly line has PLC driven traceability but the manufacturer of this one machine has the internal PLC locked out and they are unwilling to work with us to get it communicating with the PLC in the rest of the line. I'm just trying to come up with some way to match parts to the data from this machine instead of the traceability black hole that this machine currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, here is one way to get the second to last line out of a text file.

```
Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")
Dim secondToLastLine = If(lines.Count > 1, lines(lines.Count - 2), "N/A")
```